# Actions not bubbling up from Component to Route (Ember 1.13)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have one item-row.js component for each line in the CRUD and a button that triggers that "addNewItem" because I need to do some extra processing.

Well, **the action never bubbles up to the route**, so I believe I'm doing something wrong. Ember guides will tell me to do exactly what I'm doing, so I'm completely lost here. Am I missing something?

Code:

My template is like this:

```
// my-template.hbs
{{#each model as |item|}}
    {{#item-row
         id = item.id
         text = item.text
    }}
        {{item.title}}
    {{/item-row}}
{{/each}}
```

In that component's template:

```
// item-row.hbs
// a couple of HTML here
<button {{action "addNewItem"}}> </button>
```

And I have a component for that, of course

```
// item-row.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({

actions: {
        addNewItem: function(){
          this.sendAction('addNewItem');
          // already tried this.sendAction() without the parameter..
          return true;
    }
   }

});
```

And finally, my route:

```
// item.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({

    actions: {

        addNewItem: function(){
          alert('reached the route!!!!!');
          // this is never printed =/
        }

    }

});
```

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: This gets me every time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sendAction` method in the component is going to look for an attribute on the component with the same name as you pass that method, in this case `'addNewItem'`. So for your example to work, you'd need to pass `addNewItem = 'addNewItem'` to your `item-row` component, so the component knows what action to trigger on the route.

You can take a look at [this JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zajemobudo/1/edit?html,js,output) for an example of what I'm talking about. It's using globals instead of ES6 modules, but hopefully should be simple enough to follow :)

[This section](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/#toc_sending-multiple-actions) of the Ember guides may also be helpful reading.

Comment: Upvote for adding an example

Comment: sorry, forgot to set it as the answer. done :) thanks!

Comment: You should post the code in the answer (along with ember version) just in case the link dies. I can't access the link right now.